GTM - variable '_event' - return type and value is undefined
Here is my code on the site
window.dataLayer.push({ event: 'contact_form_index_en'})

But in GTM console in the Variables tab I see the following:

What is this variable _event? Where is it coming from? And why both its value and return type are undefined?
In my Data Layer tab:
{
  event: "contact_form_index_en",
  gtm: {
    uniqueEventId: 25,
    start: 1716372514378,
    allowlist: undefined,
    blocklist: undefined,
    whitelist: undefined,
    blacklist: undefined,
    priorityId: 2,
    element: "HTMLDivElement: html > body > div#__nuxt > div#__layout" +
             " > div.site > div.page.page-main.site-content > section" +
             ".blog.section > div.wrapper > section.s-contact-section" +
             " > div.s-contact-section__body > div.s-contact-section_" +
             "_col.col_right.transfade.view-in > div.s-contact-sectio" +
             "n__form.success-form#form-hoi6fa > div.contact-form > d" +
             "iv.s-button.s-button_large.s-button_white.submit-btn.ar" +
             "row",
    elementClasses: "s-button s-button_large s-button_white submit-bt" +
                    "n arrow",
    elementId: "",
    elementTarget: "",
    triggers: "6",
    elementUrl: "",
    scrollThreshold: 100,
    scrollUnits: "percent",
    scrollDirection: "vertical",
    timerId: 157,
    timerEventNumber: 2,
    timerInterval: 30000,
    timerLimit: 0,
    timerStartTime: 1716372516873,
    timerCurrentTime: 1716372576872,
    timerElapsedTime: 59999
  },
  tagTypeBlacklist: undefined
}


It looks like a bug in the Google Tag Manager Preview UI, where the _event is always undefined.
That variable returns the current value of the "event" key in dataLayer, and it's what can be used to fire triggers with.
Even with the bug, it still looks like triggers work normally, which would indicate this to be a UI bug only.
